# Node JS require without var

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

**{This has nothing to do with Twitter}**

Bit of an interesting question, interesting in that its probably stupid and you can laugh but I will have at least an answer to this damn itch.

Currently I use

```
var Bootstrap = require('library/Bootstrap');
Bootstrap.run();
```

When what would be really great is if I could do something like this in the Bootstrap index.js

```
module.exports.Bootstrap = My_Bootstrap;
```

And call it willy nilly like this

```
require('library/Bootstrap');
Bootstrap.run();
```

Without having to declare another variable to my space, is there a way to do this or am I staring at a screen wondering, dreaming, getting lost, coming back and wasting time?

**edit**
So this is what I did in the end:

I created a single global object and am only adding important modules to it so they can be accessed and instantiated. This turned out to be an amazing answer and solution and really handy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can just modify the [`global`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_global) object. This is similar to window object on browsers. So you can write a wrapper for your module like the following:

```
global.Bootstrap = My_Bootstrap
```

The global object is shared between modules. Then you can just use with `Bootstrap` wherever you are.

Comment: This is a great suggestion (doh!) I will play with this later! Thanks fellow Noder!

Comment: Just keep in mind, one of the reasons modules are helpful is because polluting the global namespace can be ugly.

Comment: That's understood, just looking at my options. I think to be honest, its only going to be for the Bootstrap and Autoloader I'm writing; I'd say that was acceptable pollution!

Comment: Please **do not** do this. People will hate you for cluttering the global space by loading your module.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you have to declare the variable. You could get inside the `require` function, though, and make that do the work for you. I'm not overly familiar with Bootstrap's internal architecture but it seems like something like this should do the trick:

```
// put this in some out-of-the-way cubbyhole somewhere
var oldRequire = require;
function require(path) {
    Bootstrap = oldRequire(path);
}

// and this would go in your main file
require("library/Bootstrap");
Bootstrap.run();
```

Comment: I didn't think there was a way but we can all dream :) Would be a fantastic treat for them to implement though! +1 for the suggestion (it has nothing to do with Twitter though ;)

Comment: This is not a very really good idea, you don't want to overwrite Node's pretty well though out module loading for your own 'make everything global' (at least to the file) method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it the way you say, that implies a global, which is almost certainly not what you want.

However what yo can do is this:

```
require('your_library').call(this,arg1,arg2);
```

For instance you could be using the [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) library.

Your are intended to use it like:

```
sanitize = require('validator').sanitize
var str = sanitize('aaaaaaaaab').ltrim('a');
```

But you can skip all that and do

```
var str = require('validator').sanitize('aaaaaaaaab').ltrim('a')
```

As far as I understand there are no downsides to doing this either in terms of memory/speed.

In your specific case, you are aware you can skip a bit...

File: MyBootStrap.js

```
Module.exports = MyBootstrap
```

File: index.js (or other)

```
require('library/Bootstrap.js')()
```